# which Logical operator i can use to meet my criteria?

Tags: java, operators

I have a scenario where my result of logical operation to achieve

```
True <op> true - true
False <op> true - false
True <op> false - true
False <op> false - true
```

Any ideas for

Comment: Seems like you have `(f1==f2)`

Comment: I was going to say `>=` until I saw the [java] tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this; here is one:

```
a || (a == b)
```